# Attribute Error: module attribute not found in defined class

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make simple Gui using pyqt and qtdesigner in Anaconda python 2.7. 
I am calling a method from inside `__init__` function. It returns attribute not found error.
Here is my code:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic, QtWidgets
from awesim.pymosim import set_pars

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
qtCreatorFile = os.path.join(dir_path , 'SimpleDymolaRun.ui' )

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, name = None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.updateParameters.clicked.connect(self.Update)
    def Update(self):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        dsin = os.path.join(dir_path, 'dsin.txt')
        value_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}
        set_pars(value_dict, dsin = os.path.join(dir_path, dsin.txt))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get following error:-

```
Traceback:
window = Myapp() 
in __init__
self.updateParameters.clicked.connect(self.Update)
AttributeError : 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'Update'
```

Am I missing something crucial in definition of **init**. I tried [suggestions in some other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974120/qt-framework-pyqt5-and-attributeerror-myapp-object-has-no-attribute-myattri), but solution mentioned therein did not work for me.
What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can nor reference a property while the object is being created

Comment: I copied the original code from the question's [edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48901289/edit), and in python3 it raises: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`. However, in python2, there is no `TabError`, and the `AttributeError` is raised instead. When the tabs are replaced with spaces, the code runs normally.

Comment: Hi ekumoro, Your comment is correct. That resolved my issue. I don't know how to accept your comment as correct answer though.